# How to plot different implicit equation in the same graph using python sumpy plot implicit

Tags: python, sympy

I want to plot different equations in the same graph using python sympy plot_implicit.

Below is my sample code but this doesn't function correctly.
Now the implicit function is just circle but I want to deal more complicated
equation in the near future.

Moreover, I want to plot the coordinate points(given as "points" in the sample code) in the same graph too.

Can anyone solve this quation?

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import plot
from sympy.plotting import plot_implicit

points = np.array([[10,20], [20, 75], [45, 15], [70, 53], [90, 30]])
weights = np.array([5, 5.1, 5.2, 4.9, 4.8])

x, y = symbols("x y")

 for i in range(len(points)):
  G = (x-points[i][0])**2 + (y-points[i][1])**2 - weights[i]**2   
  p2 = plot_implicit(G, (x,-50,100), (y,-50,100), show=False, line_color='r')
  p2.extend(p2)

p2.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise. It has a great help for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p2.extend(p2)` is wrong, you never want to extend a plot by itself. In addition, whatever you did to `p2` in one run of the loop is wiped out by the following run, because you are *assigning* to `p2` within a loop.

You need a separate variable, say `p`, as an accumulator of the plots. Let's initialize it with None before the loop and then either assign p2 to it (on the initial run), or extend it by p2 (on subsequent runs). The condition `if p` works for this purpose: `None` is falsy, but objects, including Plot objects, are truthy.

```
p = None
for i in range(len(points)):
  G = (x-points[i][0])**2 + (y-points[i][1])**2 - weights[i]**2   
  p2 = plot_implicit(G, (x,-50,100), (y,-50,100), show=False, line_color='r')
  if p:
    p.extend(p2)
  else:
    p = p2

p.show()
```